# Handle Raspberry Pi camera via Apache

Tags: php, apache, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm trying to get an image of the raspi camera via a php script.
It's installed php5, apache2 and all necessary stuff.

**Snippet: `/var/www/img.php`**

```
if(isset($_GET['pic']))
    system("sudo raspistill -w 512 -h 320 -o /var/www/img/img.jpg");
```

When I run the command directly in the terminal it's working, but the php script not. With `sudo php /var/www/img.php?pic` I'll get an error:

```
Could not read input file: /var/www/img.php
```

First I thought it's a problem with the permissions, but isn't working even with root privileges.

Have anybody an idea? I'm really depressed..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) instead of `system()`.

Comment: Already done. Also exec_shell, popen, fopen/fread/fclose,...

Comment: And they all fail? Anything in the error logs?

Comment: yep, all failed. 
One single entry refererring the favicon :P

Comment: Btw: a command like `sudo touch test.txt` isn't working too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

first it's necessary to change the owner of the apache directory:

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www
```

After that it's not necessary to prepend `sudo`:

```
exec('raspistill ...');
```

It's also possible with `popen`, `system`, ...